# SonataAdminBundle and FOSUserBundle error message for security.role_hierarchy.roles

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I use `FosUserBundle` and `SonataUserBundle` for my `Symfony2` project.
I've got error message:

```
The service "sonata.user.editable_role_builder" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter `security.role_hierarchy.roles`
```

Comment: same here any guess ?

Comment: @KarolGontarski Have a look into my answer, if the issue is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is really simple, you have forgotten to create a *security.yml* containing the role hierachy.

I think you have skipped [step 4](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.3.x/Resources/doc/index.md#step-4-configure-your-applications-securityyml) of installing FOSUserBundle (see last part of configuration).

> Below is a minimal example of the configuration necessary to use the FOSUserBundle in your application:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```